# I've installed Jetpack but can't edit the CSS to my blog?

Tags: plugins, plugin-jetpack

I have a personal WordPress blog that I've used for years. Recently for an assignment at university, they assigned us to make a blog, and they gave us our individual URLs on WordPress. On my university WordPress, I have Jetpack installed and running because part of the assessment was to edit the blog's appearance with CSS. I installed Jetpack using my university email.

Now I want to edit my personal blog's CSS. It says that I already have Jetpack installed however there is no Additional CSS feature when I try to customize my theme. I am running on the Sketch theme.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: you need to ask whioever is responsible for setting up the site how can you make changes to the CSS. If you do not have the permissionto edit code files or change the css with the built in functionality, thn you simply can not do it

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need Jetpack to edit custom CSS on your site. WordPress supports this out of the box

You can head to Appearance -> Customize where'll you see a section to add Additional CSS:

[image: Add Additional CSS]

You need at least WordPress 4.7 and the `edit_css` capability to see this section. By default this capability maps to `unfiltered_html`, which only admins (or super admins on multisite) have.

The [Custom CSS](https://jetpack.com/support/custom-css/) module in Jetpack improves that feature a little bit and changes that capability mapping to `edit_theme_options` (still something only admins have by default). Of course you need to activate it first.

When you don't see an "Additional CSS" section, make sure you're an admin and try disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme like Twenty Seventeen.